# I cannot add unzip

Tags: javascript, typescript, yarnpkg

I am Japanese beginner web developer.

And I am not good at english.

I am sorry.

I want to use this module.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/unzip

So I did `yarn add unzip` and `yarn add fs` and `yarn add module v8` and `yarn add request@2.79.0`.

And I did

```
var fs = require('fs');
var unzip = require('unzip');
```

but because of "require('unzip')" , I get error.

> Uncaught Error: No such module. (Possibly not yet loaded)

And I got this error when build.

> WARNING  Compiled with 3 warnings                                                                                                                                                    16:03:20
>
> warning  in ./node_modules/natives/index.js
>
> Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
>
> warning  in ./node_modules/lazy-debug-legacy/src/functions.js
>
> Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
>
> warning in./node_modules/lazy-debug-legacy/src/functions.js
>
> Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

Any one tell me the way to solve this?
I can't use unzip module.

And I used this module too.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/unzipper

but if I did

```
var unzipper = require('unzipper');
```

I got different error.

> polyfills.js?a0a3:32 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'match'
>   of undefined

My full code.

```
//converter.ts
var fs = require('fs');
var unzipper = require('unzipper');

export default function converter(file) {

    console.log(file)

    //     fs.createReadStream(file)
    //         .pipe(unzipper.Extract({ path: './tmp/' }));

}
```

---

```
//convert.vue
<template>

  <div class="convert">

  </div>

</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Prop, Vue } from "vue-property-decorator";

import converter from "./converter"

@Component({
  components: {}
})
export default class Convert extends Vue {

    mounted(){
        converter("./resources/text.zip")
    }

}
</script>

<style lang="scss">
</style>
```

Comment: Your english is kinda ok, but if you feel like you'd rather write in Japanese you could check out https://ja.stackoverflow.com/ instead.

Comment: Thank you. But there are better developers in here(T____T)

Comment: What does `node --version` say? Did you add it with `yarn add unzip` or `npm i -S unzip`?

Comment: node -v is "v9.5.0" and I added with yarn!!! And I am doing with vue-cli3.0.

Comment: You are trying to use that library in the browser (Vue.js)?

Comment: Well , yes.  I made ts file that imports unzip , and I am importing  that ts file to .vue file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use 'fs' or 'unzip' in a browser environment. They are meant to be used in a Node.js runtime. Javascript executing in a web page doesn't have access to the underlying filesystem. (There is [Filesystem API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystem), but it's only a virtual filesystem and only chrome supports it)

If you want to work with a simulated filesystem in a cross browser environment, you can probably take a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-web.

Answer (score 0):

This library isn't meant to be used in the browser environment - it depends on Node.js specific modules, which aren't available in the browser.

Comment: It's impossible to use it in the browser. You need a Node.js back-end server - you can use it there.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install `unzip` with the `--save` or `--save-dev` flag.

`yarn add --save unzip` so your applicate can resolve it via the *package.json*

**EDIT**

`fs` works because it is a Node.Js build in.